# Error while starting hadoop

Tags: permissions, hadoop, virtual-terminal

When I try to run hadoop as `bin/start-all.sh`, I get this error.:

```
 mkdir: cannot create directory /home/prasanna/Desktop/hadoop/libexec/../logs: Permission denied  

 chown: cannot access /home/prasanna/Desktop/hadoop/libexec/../logs: No such file or directory  

 starting namenode, logging to /home/prasanna/Desktop/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-prasanna-namenode-prasanna-VirtualBox.out  

 /home/prasanna/Desktop/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 135: /home/prasanna/Desktop/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-prasanna-namenode-prasanna-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory  

 head: cannot open /home/prasanna/Desktop/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-prasanna-namenode-prasanna-VirtualBox.out for reading: No such file or directory
```

What would be the reason and how should I fix this?

PS: I am very new to Linux

Comment: I think this answer can solve your problem: http://askubuntu.com/a/263454/65926

Comment: @EricCarvalho: When I try "sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME", it says "chown: cannot access `/home/prasanna/.gvfs': Permission denied"

Comment: That's expected. Try to run hadoop again.

Answer (score -2):

The user you're using doesn't have root permission to create the folder in Desktop so use the `sudo` command:

example:

```
cd hadoop/bin
sudo ./start-all.sh
```