# Folders showing lock

Tags: directory

Whenever I open my documents, all the folders in it are displayed with a lock icon. Therefore, I cannot delete any file or folder in it.and also can't change folder permission.so, give me solution how to fix this problem

Comment: Did you check who is the owner of these folders?

Comment: Look at the answers of this question: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/263450/folders-showing-lock-icon?rq=1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263450/folders-showing-lock-icon?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you somehow lost ownership of these directories.

Run the command below in a terminal to gain ownership of all files and folders in your home directory recursively:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```