# Ubuntu 20.04 occasionally freezes shortly after login Ext4 Journal Failure

Tags: filesystem, ssd, ext4, read-only, data-corruption

I have an Asus laptop with newly installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04, installed on dev/sdb2, a 1TB Crucial M.2 SSD.

Fairly often (about 50% of the time), shortly after I login and begin working, Ubuntu will close all open apps and freeze.  It seems to be a slow process, where the apps close, then the Budgie DE will stop, and finally the mouse becomes unresponsive.  At this point, I am able to use CTRL + F2 to access a login screen, but when I provide the username, it throws error:

```
[   844.940093] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1009020696 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

Then presents the login prompt again.  If I try to login a second time, I get a lot of systemd alerts:

```
[   861.655386] systemd-journald[376]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 745 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[   861.655543] systemd-journald[376]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 756 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[   861.655835] systemd-journald[376]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 745 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[   861.656284] systemd-journald[376]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 756 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[   861.656532] systemd-journald[376]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 745 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
```

At this point, I force shutdown by holding the power button, restart, and the system usually works fine for the next boot.

I have been monitoring the disks SMART test, and it consistently shows 2 bad blocks.  I have tried completely formatting the drive and reinstalling the OS, with no luck.

I have been searching the forums and googling the error messages with no success.

Is this a hardware error and I need to have my drive replaced, or something software that can be fixed?  Also, I'm trying to learn the Ubuntu system still, so if someone could explain what the errors mean, that would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to update this, as I have figured out the problem.

After multiple reinstalls of Budgie, and an install of Kubuntu, I figured out that it was indeed a hardware problem; my SSD had failed.  I contacted Crucial and told them about the I/O error, and they confirmed it was failing hardware and helped me replace it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From where have you been monitoring the S.M.A.R.T results. Running it from the Bios sometimes breaks the filesystem.having 2 bad blocks is nothing your system should be able to run smoothly.Have a look at this [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 18.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1)
Also i would suggest not to force poweroff the system. Doing so results in more corruptions. You might also want to take a look at this later if your files are locked.If you don't have enough permissions for modifying your files. [https://askubuntu.com/questions/263450/folders-showing-lock-icon\](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263450/folders-showing-lock-icon%5C)

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have been monitoring the SMART results through the Disks utility included with Ubuntu.  I believe the 2 blocks have been bad since I received the drive.  I tend not to force poweroff, and only have been because nothing else works.

Comment: Have you tried suspending  the system when the machine is slowing down and bring it back up again. I'll say, this is no proven solution. its just a shot out in the dark.

Comment: I tried pressing the suspend key when it was going down, but it had no results.